# Add Success Message in Custom Popup for Add to Compare in the listing or Category Page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax, jquery, modal-popup, compare

I want to add custom pop-up in category page for showing success or error message for add to compare button.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have update and add the logic for custom popup for Add to compare, please refer the solution for the same,

> create di.xml in app/code/Abc/Xyz/etc/frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add">
        <plugin name="ajax_compare_plugin" type="Abc\Xyz\Plugin\Controller\Product\Compare\Add"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> create routes.xml in
> app/code/Abc/Xyz/etc/frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="ajaxcompare" frontName="ajaxcompare">
            <module name="Abc_Xyz" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> create Add.php in Abc\Xyz\Plugin\Controller\Product\Compare

```
<?php

namespace Abc\Xyz\Plugin\Controller\Product\Compare;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Add
 * @package Abc\Xyz\Plugin\Controller\Product\Compare
 */
class Add extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add
{

    /**
     * Init popup ajax compare
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($subject->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            $this->_view->loadLayout();
            $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
            $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            try {
                /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $product = null;
            }

            if ($product) {
                $this->_catalogProductCompareList->addProduct($product);
                $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_compare_add_product', ['product' => $product]);
                $response = [];
                $popup    = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct')
                                        ->setData('product', $product)
                                        ->setTemplate('Abc_Xyz::popup.phtml')
                                        ->toHtml();
                $response['success'] = true;
                $response['popup']   = $popup;
                $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
                $resultJson->setData($response);
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare::class)->calculate();
                return $resultJson;
            }

            return false;
        }

        return $result;

    }

}
```

> create default.xml in app/code/Abc/Xyz/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.compare.js" as="ajaxCompareJs" template="Abc_Xyz::js.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> create js.phtml in app/code/Abc/Xyz/view/frontend/templates/js.phtml

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "body": {
        "abc/xyz" : {
            "popupTTL"       : "<?php echo "10"; ?>",
            "showLoader"     : "<?php echo "0"; ?>"        
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

> create popup.phtml in app/code/Abc/Xyz/view/templates

```
<?php 
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_grid';
?>
<div class="compare-popup-border ajaxcompare-success-box">
    <div class="ajax-compare-image">
        <h2 class="product-name"><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></h2>
    </div>
    <h3 class="message-successs"><?php echo __('You added this product to the comparison list') ?></h3>
    <div class="ajaxcompare-buttons">
        <button type="button" id="ajaxcompare_btn_close_popup" class="action primary compare-close" title="<?php echo __('Close') ?>">
            <span><?php echo __('Close ') ?></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="ajaxcompare_checkout" class="action focus primary"
                title="<?php echo __('View Comparison') ?>"
                onClick="window.location='<?php echo $block->getUrl('catalog/product_compare/index/'); ?>'">
            <span><?php echo __('View Comparison List') ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

> create ajax-compare.js in app/code/Abc/Xyz/view/frontend/web/js

define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
'mage/translate',
'jquery/ui',
], function ($, modal, $t) {
'use strict';

```
$.widget('abc.xyz',{

    options: {
        popupWrapperSelector: '#compare-popup-wrapper',
        popupBlankSelector: '#compare-blank',
        closePopupModal: '.action-close',
        processStart: 'processStart',
        processStop : 'processStop',
        addToCompareButtonSelector: '.tocompare',
        addToCompareButtonDisabledClass: 'disabled',
        addToCompareButtonTextWhileAdding: '',
        addToCompareButtonTextAdded: '',
        addToCompareButtonTextDefault: '',
        btnCloseSelector: '#ajaxcompare_btn_close_popup',
        showLoader: false
    },

     _create: function () {
        var self = this;
        self._init();
        $('body').on('contentUpdated', function () {
            self._init();
        });
    },

    autoClosePopup: function (wrapper) {
        var self = this;
        var autocloseCountdown = setInterval(function (wrapper) {
                var leftTimeNode = $('body').find('#ajaxcompare_btn_close_popup .compare-autoclose-countdown');
                var leftTime = parseInt(leftTimeNode.text()) - 1;                   
                leftTimeNode.text(leftTime);
                if (leftTime == 0) {
                    clearInterval(autocloseCountdown);
                    self.closePopup();
                }
        }, 1000);
    },

    closePopup: function () {
        $(this.options.popupWrapperSelector).fadeOut('slow');
        $(this.options.popupBlankSelector).fadeOut('slow');
        $(this.options.closePopupModal).trigger('click');
    },

    _init: function () {
        var self = this;
        $('body').on('click', self.options.btnCloseSelector, function (e) {
            self.closePopup();
        });

        self.element.find(self.options.addToCompareButtonSelector).off('click').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            self.addCompare($(this));
        });

    },

    showPopup: function() {
        var self = this,
            comparePopup = $(self.options.popupWrapperSelector);
        var modaloption = {
            type: 'popup',
            modalClass: 'modal-popup_ajaxcompare',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            clickableOverlay: true,
            closed: function(){
               $('.modal-popup_ajaxcompare').remove();
            }
        };
        modal(modaloption, comparePopup);
        comparePopup.modal('openModal');
    },

    addCompare: function (el) {
        var self = this, 
            comparePopup = $(self.options.popupWrapperSelector),
            body   = $('body'),
            parent = el.parent(),
            post   = el.data('post');
        var params = post.data;
        if(parent.hasClass(self.options.addToCompareButtonDisabledClass)) return;
        $.ajax({
            url: post.action,
            data: params,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            showLoader: self.options.showLoader,
            beforeSend: function () {
                self.disableAddToCompareButton(parent);
                if (self.options.showLoader) body.trigger(self.options.processStart);
            },
            success: function (res) {
                if (self.options.showLoader) body.trigger(self.options.processStop);
                if (res.popup) {
                    if (!comparePopup.length) {
                        body.append('<div class="compare-popup-wrapper" id="' + self.options.popupWrapperSelector.replace(/^#/, "") +'" >'+res.popup+'</div>');
                    }
                    self.showPopup();                     
                    self.autoClosePopup(self.options.popupWrapperSelector);                      
                } else {
                    alert($t('No response from server'));
                }
            }
        }).done(function(){
             self.enableAddToCompareButton(parent);
        });
    },

    /**
     * @param {String} form
     */
    disableAddToCompareButton: function (form) {
        var addToCompareButtonTextWhileAdding = this.options.addToCompareButtonTextWhileAdding || $t('Adding...'),
            addToCompareButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCompareButtonSelector);

        addToCompareButton.addClass(this.options.addToCompareButtonDisabledClass);
        addToCompareButton.find('span').text(addToCompareButtonTextWhileAdding);
        addToCompareButton.attr('title', addToCompareButtonTextWhileAdding);
    },

    /**
     * @param {String} form
     */
    enableAddToCompareButton: function (form) {
        var addToCompareButtonTextAdded = this.options.addToCompareButtonTextAdded || $t('Added'),
            self = this,
            addToCompareButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCompareButtonSelector);

        addToCompareButton.find('span').text(addToCompareButtonTextAdded);
        addToCompareButton.attr('title', addToCompareButtonTextAdded);

        setTimeout(function () {
            var addToCompareButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCompareButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Compare');

            addToCompareButton.removeClass(self.options.addToCompareButtonDisabledClass);
            addToCompareButton.find('span').text(addToCompareButtonTextDefault);
            addToCompareButton.attr('title', addToCompareButtonTextDefault);
        }, 1000);
    }

});

return $.abc.xyz;
```

});

> create requirejs-config.js in app/code/Abc/Xyz/view/frontend

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'abc/xyz': 'Abc_Xyz/js/ajax-compare'
            
        }
    }
};
```

Don't forgot to create registration.php and module.xml, if you are creating separate module for this...
Please upvote the answer if it's useful !!!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Refer to this tutorial link:- https://itecnotes.com/magento/magento-custom-popup-message-while-add-to-compare-on-product-list-page/

Comment: Did you test the code from the link?